# Earliest record of opposition towards Mawlid

Tags: history, fiqh, bidah

As far as I've researched, the earliest record of yearly Mawlid of Nabi SAW (between 12-17 Rabi Ul Awwal) is during the 1100s initiated by the fatimids [1]. What I want to know is when they started doing the mawlid of Nabi SAW, is there any scholar who opposed this ? To summarize, my question is, what is the earliest known opposition of the Mawlid of Nabi SAW?

1. Katz, Marion Holmes (2007). The Birth of The Prophet Muhammad: Devotional Piety in Sunni Islam

Comment: Define Mawlid. The Prophet PBUH used to fast a specific day a week because it was his birthday - that’s a Mawlid.

Comment: AFAIK and my research, the earliest record of Mawlid is from the era of prophet Muhammad(صلى الله عليه وسلم ) and it is not initiated by the fatimids.

Comment: @Shadi, i edited to mention it as the yearly mawlid

Comment: @Ali786, I've referenced my answer with an evidence, can you provide a reference for what you are saying so that I can insert it in my question

Comment: @Noor, No offence but, the book you have added in reference, is written in 2007 and not accepted worlwide.

Comment: @Ali786, yeah but this is the only ref I have that's y i'm asking your ref so that i can modify my question, there is no reason to be offended

Answer (score -1):

The celebration of the Prophet Muhammad's birthday, known as Mawlid or Milad-un-Nabi, is a practice that has been observed by Muslims for centuries. While the celebration has been widely accepted and celebrated throughout Islamic history, there have been occasional oppositions to this practice as well.

One of the earliest records of opposition to Mawlid can be traced back to the 12th century CE, during the time of the famous Islamic scholar and theologian Ibn Taymiyyah. Ibn Taymiyyah was known for his conservative views and opposition to what he considered to be innovations (bid'ah) in Islamic practice.

In his writings, Ibn Taymiyyah criticized the practice of Mawlid, arguing that it was an innovation that had no basis in the Quran or the Sunnah (teachings and practices of the Prophet Muhammad). He claimed that the early Muslims did not celebrate Mawlid, and that the practice had been introduced later as an innovation by some groups.

Ibn Taymiyyah's views on Mawlid were not universally accepted, and there were other scholars who defended the practice as a legitimate way of expressing love and respect for the Prophet Muhammad. Nevertheless, his writings had a significant influence on the debate over the legitimacy of Mawlid, and his views continue to be cited by some who oppose the practice.

It's important to note that while there have been occasional oppositions to the practice of Mawlid throughout Islamic history, the celebration has been widely accepted and celebrated by Muslims in various parts of the world. Today, Mawlid remains a popular and joyous occasion for many Muslims around the world, and is celebrated in a variety of ways depending on local customs and traditions.
To find out more about this please follow the link:
https://www.islamiqate.com/285/why-salafis-focus-much-mawlid-and-not-much-saudi-national-day